# python ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected ....)

Tags: python

I have defined the following function that takes an input string, and compares it to a large list of strings (both vectorized using tfidf):

```
def find_new_similar(tfidf_matrix2, index, tfidf_matrix, top_n = 5):
    cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix2[index:index+1], tfidf_matrix).flatten()
    related_docs_indices = [i for i in cosine_similarities.argsort()[::-1] if i != index]
    return [(i, cosine_similarities[i]) for i in related_docs_indices][0:top_n], index
```

when I call this function my output is:

```
    find_new_similar(tfidf_matrix2, 1, tfidf_matrix)
    Out[15]: 
    ([(923576, 0.51192576542407131),
      (558563, 0.51192576542407131),
      (1554977, 0.51192576542407131),
      (1604772, 0.51192576542407131),
      (514529, 0.50251903670563314)],
     1)
```

where the first element of each tuple (ie. 923576, 558563) is an index for a large file of terms. I would like to use these indexes and return the value at the index.

```
I have tried:


for i, score in find_new_similar(tfidf_matrix2, 0, tfidf_matrix):
       print (score, corpus[i], i)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-792db65f6fd0>", line 1, in <module>
    for i, score in find_new_similar(tfidf_matrix2, 0, tfidf_matrix):

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

can anyone help? thanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You function returns a list and `index`

```
return [(i, cosine_similarities[i]) for i in related_docs_indices][0:top_n], index
```

change your code to

```
for i, score in find_new_similar(tfidf_matrix2, 0, tfidf_matrix)[0]:
       print (score, corpus[i], i)
```

to get the list and iterate over it.